# C# equivalent of VB LINQ Query

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have the following query in VB, but I do not know how to translate it to C# synatax

```
 Dim q = From c In db.Customers
        Group Join o In db.Orders On c.CustomerID Equals o.CustomerID Into orders = Group 
        Select New With {c.ContactName, .OrderCount = orders.Count()}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy. You just have to drop the "Group":

```
var q = from c in db.Customers
        join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into orders
        select new { c.ContactName, OrderCount = orders.Count() };
```

Or, if you're looking for the lambda syntax:

```
var q = db.Customers.GroupJoin(db.Orders,
                               o => o.CustomerID,
                               c => c.CustomerID,
                               (c, orders) =>
                                   new
                                   {
                                       c.ContactName, 
                                       OrderCount = orders.Count()
                                   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim q = From c In db.Customers
    Group Join o In db.Orders On c.CustomerID Equals o.CustomerID Into orders = Group 
    Select New With {c.ContactName, .OrderCount = orders.Count()}

var q =
    from c in db.Customers
    join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into orders
    select new {c.ContactName, .OrderCount = orders.Count()};
```

Comment: bah, Justin is much quicker than I, and doesn't forget semicolons :P